# i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined" everytime i click on the image

Tags: javascript

i tried to make an element appear after a user clicks on an image. i used classlist.toggle for that but when i click on the image the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined"  appears in the console. And of course it is not working

```js
const plusbtn = document.querySelector(".btn-img");
const drop = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")

plusbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drop.classList.toggle("box-drop");
})
```

```css
.boxes {
  border: 1px solid rgba(39, 81, 197, 0.39);
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-img {
  align-self: center;
  filter: grayscale(50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-drop {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>RESOURCES</h1>
  <div class="resource-boxes">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="top">
        <img src="../images/plus.png" alt="" class="btn-img">
      </div>
      <div class="boxes">
        <a href="">
          <div class="minibox">
            <span class="minibox-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam, enim! </span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). You need to loop every element in that collection in order to access it.

***But***, since you already use `.querySelector()` you could as well

- use [`.querySelectorAll()` which returns a NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which offers by default a [`.forEach()` Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- Instead of hiding elements where they are styles-defined, use instead a reusable utility class like `.u-none{ display: none; }`

```js
const EL_btnPlus = document.querySelector(".btn-img");
const ELS_drop   = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");

EL_btnPlus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ELS_drop.forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("u-none"));
});
```

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="btn-img" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJzyljorAsMuzZ3OQ6B7g_2EU0bkA4lk3iH076AR=k-s64" alt="">

<div class="boxes u-none">Box one</div>
<div class="boxes u-none">Box two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`drop` is a list of elements (see the [return value of `getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)). You have to loop through it and toggle the class on each individual element:

```js
const plusbtn = document.querySelector(".btn-img");
const drop = [...document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")];

plusbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  drop.forEach(e => e.classList.toggle("box-drop"));
})
```

```css
.boxes {
  border: 1px solid rgba(39, 81, 197, 0.39);
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn-img {
  align-self: center;
  filter: grayscale(50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-drop {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>RESOURCES</h1>
  <div class="resource-boxes">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="top">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="" class="btn-img">
      </div>
      <div class="boxes">
        <a href="">
          <div class="minibox">
            <span class="minibox-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Numquam, enim! </span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```